# how to add a prediction layer for 4 different class images

Tags: tensorflow

from tensorflow sample https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning, it add prediction_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1) to predict dogs and cats, However what if I have 4 different categories images, should I justadd another prediction layers? Is there any proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `prediction_layer = keras.layers.Dense(4)` and you will need to change the training label to `[1,0,0,0]` where each index represents the classes(dog ,cat, fish, bird).

Also you will have to read up on `Softmax` and `Cross-Entropy Function`.

The predictions can be thought of as probability that it is of a particular class. Example: `[0.2, 0.7, 0.0, 0.1] means its 70% a dog`.